# some guidance in modifying the query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm using the below query in order to split the value of a column into another column and is working fine, but it is not giving the output that I'm expecting. Below is the query along with the output.

### Query:

```
SELECT 
  upper(regexp_substr(db_attributes, '[^,:]+$',1,1)) AS servername,
   db_attributes FROM
table_name
```

### Current Output:

```
Servername                                 db_attributes
INPRD1HF                                   hkp04lp0605s-rs6000.hk.hsbc, 50000, AP4INPU1:INPRD1HF
AE000BDS0096\LIVE0096MSSQL                ae000bds0096.hbeu.adroot.hsbc, 60695, AE000BDS0096\LIVE0096MSSQL
NULL                                      ora-abacogp.de.hsbc, 1626, ABACOGP
```

### Desired output:

```
Servername                                 db_attributes
AP4INPU1                                   hkp04lp0605s-rs6000.hk.hsbc, 50000, AP4INPU1:INPRD1HF
AE000BDS0096\LIVE0096MSSQL                ae000bds0096.hbeu.adroot.hsbc, 60695, AE000BDS0096\LIVE0096MSSQL
ABACOGP                                   ora-abacogp.de.hsbc, 1626, ABACOGP
```

The difference between the current and desired output is in the first line I want the value which is before colon in `db_attributes` column (i.e. `AP4INPU1` not `INPRD1HF`)

Regards,

Vikas

Comment: Try `([^,:[:space:]]+)(:\S*)?$`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
regexp_substr(db_attributes, '([^,:[:space:]]+)(:\S*)?$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

**Details**

- `([^,:[:space:]]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `,`, `:` and whitespace chars
- `(:\S*)?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 sequences of `:` and then 0+ non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

See the [online tests](http://rextester.com/XEKYP41501):

```
--select regexp_substr('hkp04lp0605s-rs6000.hk.hsbc, 50000, AP4INPU1:INPRD1HF', '([^,:[:space:]]+)(:\S*)?$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS servername from dual
-- => AP4INPU1
--select regexp_substr('ora-abacogp.de.hsbc, 1626, ABACOGP', '([^,:[:space:]]+)(:\S*)?$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS servername from dual
-- => ABACOGP
--
select regexp_substr('ae000bds0096.hbeu.adroot.hsbc, 60695, AE000BDS0096\LIVE0096MSSQL', '([^,:[:space:]]+)(:\S*)?$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS servername from dual
-- => AE000BDS0096\LIVE0096MSSQL
```